# Angular/Typescript - Get data from array services

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, filter, service

I'm trying to retrieve data from an array in my services through a get function. I'm aware that I can use the .filter or .find functions, however, I'm really getting confused about the execution and after many tries I was unable to retrieve the information. I can understand that this may considered a very basic question but I'm fairly new to this. Any help would be really appreciated.

tracker-data.ts:

```
export class TrackerData {
  entry?: number;
  exit?: number;
  clicks: string[] = [];
  url?: string;

  public get clickCount(): number
  { return this.clicks.length; }
}
```

tracker.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TrackerData } from '../modules/tracker-data';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TrackerService {
  websiteData: TrackerData[] = [];

  public count = 0;

  constructor() { }

  addTrackerData(trackerData: TrackerData): void {
    this.websiteData.push(trackerData);
   }

   getData() {
      return this.websiteData;
   }
}
```

summary.component.ts (where the data should be displayed)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TrackerService } from 'src/app/services/tracker.service';
import { TrackerData } from 'src/app/modules/tracker-data';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-summary',
  templateUrl: './summary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summary.component.scss']
})
export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit {
  websiteData: TrackerData[] = [];

  constructor(
    private trackerService: TrackerService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  getData(){
    this.websiteData = this.trackerService.getData();
    console.log(this.websiteData);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you're receiving? And please explain the `getData()` function the service. Why does it return it's own argument back. It should be `return this.websiteData;`.

Comment: Initially, I did it that way, but simply changed for testing purposes and forgot to change it back. Apologies for that.

Comment: Could you please say what actually the error is? Do you not get the array in the component?

Comment: I can't see where you are using the addTrackerData() method. Put a console.log  on addTrackerData() method before the push, like this: console.log(trackerData), to see what's getting into the array, if it's called

Comment: I'm not getting any particular error. It's just that I'm not retrieving the data in the array through the console log. The addTrackerdata is a different function that works. My problem revolves around the getdata function as I'm unable to see the data in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not receiving the data in the log because the function isn't being called anywhere in the code and it's also not being used in any of the lifecycle events. To initialize data from a service it is common to call functions from services in the `ngOnInit` lifeCycle event. This seems to be what you are trying to do so you should call the `trackerService.getData()` function there.

It would look something like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 this.websiteData = this.trackerService.getData();
    console.log(this.websiteData);
  }
```

There are more ways to call the function, it is possible to call the function in the constructor(when the component is being created) but this is not standard practice. Functions can also be triggered when an event occurs on your webpage, for example when a user clicks on a button.

I suggest you look more into the Angular documentation though because it's very good and explains all the basics in better detail: https://angular.io/docs